# Adding a content reference only on a xna game library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna, clickonce

First of all I'm going to give you a little background on this issue.
My solution has 2 windows forms projects (map editor and another tool), one XNA game, a game library and a content project.

Im adding the content reference to the library, which is referenced by the forms and the game. This way I thought I would be able to access the content everywhere, making everything easier.

It worked until I tried to deploy the project using the ClickOnce feature. When I try to do that, I get a:

**Error 1   Unable to load arguments for the XmlPeek task. One of XmlContent or XmlInputPath arguments must be set.**

And I have no idea of the reason for this error. Now I cant even debug with this setup. It used to work, until I tried to use ClickOnce publishing, and now not even debugging works. i have to add a content reference to the game, and remove it from the Library, because having the game and the library referencing the same content project gets me 1 error for each one of my content files.

Any thought on this error message?

Comment: dead link in the above comment

Comment: Fixed link: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/65798/402760.aspx

Comment: @JeremyThompson,  Since the XBOX forums are now officially dead, could you please provide the substance of the post as an answer to the question. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”
Your comment has become the "de facto" answer to this question, at 735 views.